# HttpClient asyncRequest and exponential backoff

Tags: java, spring-boot, async-await, exponential-backoff

I need to implement an exponential backoff on a request that might fail. However, it's implemented as an async request. Had this been done synchronously, I'd have a better idea on where to put the delay. Roughly, I'm thinking it'd work something like this:

```
// These would be configurable in application.yml
currentAttempt = 0;
maxAttempts = 3;
timeoutGrowth = 2;
currentDelayTime = 5ms;
repeatNeeded = false;
while(repeatNeeded && currentAttempt < maxAttempts) {
    httpStatusCode = makeRequest(someService)
    if(httpStatusCode == 503) {
        repeatNeeded=true;
        currentAttempt++;
        currentDelayTime*=timeoutGrowthRate;
        sleep(currentDelayTime)
    }
}
```

However, with an async call, the caller to the function is given the time back to do something else until the Future is has something. Do I code the backoff within the getObservations() method below, or do I code this in the caller of that getObservations() method? Below is the call as it currently is:

```
public CompletableFuture<ToolResponse> getObservations(String text, Map<String, Object> bodyParams) throws URISyntaxException {
        URI uri = getUri(text);
        HttpRequest request = getRequest(uri, text, bodyParams);
        Map<String, String> contextMap = Optional.ofNullable(MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()).orElse(Collections.emptyMap());

        Instant startTime = Instant.now();

        return httpClient.sendAsync(request, BodyHandlers.ofString())
                .exceptionally(ex -> {
                    throw new ExternalToolException(externalServiceConfig.getName(), ex);
                })
                .thenApply(response -> {
                    long toolRequestDurationMillis = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(startTime, Instant.now());
                    if (HttpStatus.valueOf(response.statusCode()).is2xxSuccessful()) {
                        ToolResponse toolResponse = processResponse(response, toolRequestDurationMillis);
                        logToolResponse(toolResponse);
                        return toolResponse;
                    }

                    log.error("{} returned non-200 response code: {}", externalServiceConfig.getName(), response.statusCode());
                    throw new ExternalToolException(externalServiceConfig.getName(), response.statusCode());
                });
}
```

Comment: if you could consider using reactive java, it has very powerful API including retries For example,`.retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(2)));` You could use`WebClient` that is non-blocking, reactive client  or wrap `CompletableFeature` using `Mono.fromFuture`

Comment: @Alex This looks like a great answer. Just to be clear, did you mean CompletableFuture? I wonder how this would work if the caller were say an Angular server, and not an internal Java code. That is, how would it return for a little bit, then come back when the real result was ready. Anyway, I'd like to give you credit for your answer, would you please post as such?

Comment: yeah `CompletableFuture` ;-). non-blocking means that all I/O operations are async and event-driven (think event loop) small number of threads to scale. This model is similar to node.js. There is no difference for client that will get results when ready but server-side processing is more efficient. 
You can find some examples in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could consider using reactive java that has very powerful API including retries. For example,

```
request()
  .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(1)));
```

there are more options like retries for the specific exceptions only or defining max backoff

```
request()
  .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(2)));
  .maxBackoff(5)
  .filter(throwable -> isRetryableError(throwable))
```

You could use `WebClient` that is a non-blocking client exposing a fluent, reactive API over underlying HTTP client libraries such as Reactor Netty

```
webClient.get()
        .uri("/api")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(1)));
```

if for some reason, you still want to use HttpClient you can wrap `CompletableFuture`

```
Mono.fromFuture(httpClient.sendAsync(request, BodyHandlers.ofString()))
  .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(1)));
```

Comment: I forgot to ask which package has the reactive client. Plus one for giving the maven dependency and the import statement(s).

Comment: WebClient is in `org.springframework.boot:spring-webflux`. if you need just api - `io.projectreactor:reactor-core`

Comment: For sping boot - `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux`

Comment: Spring Reactive `WebClient` supports configurable http connectors using Java 11 Client, Reactor, Apache HttpClient5 etc.